# Explain why function won't execute when button clicked

Tags: javascript

I can't get the button within the signIn function to execute on the onclick event. I need help understanding what I am doing wrong and what needs to be done to fix it. I am building a simple silly app to learn javascript/typescript. The other buttons earlier in the app work and I am able to transform the DOM but the button built within the signin function doesn't seem to fire and execute the isValid function. I have no errors within the web console. I am completely stumped as to why the button will not execute the isValid function.

```js
  var App = /** @class */ (function () {
  function App() {
      this.init();
  }
  App.prototype.init = function () {
      if (!window['WebSocket']) {
          console.log("BROWSER NOT SUPPORTED");
          document.body.innerHTML = "BROWSER NOT SUPPORTED";
      }
      document.documentElement.style.background = "green";
      document.title = "App";
      var sin = document.createElement("button");
      sin.id = "sin";
      sin.innerHTML = "SIGN IN";
      sin.onclick = this.signIn;
      var sup = document.createElement("button");
      sup.id = "signup";
      sup.innerHTML = "SIGN UP";
      sup.onclick = this.signUp;
      var landing = document.createElement("div");
      landing.id = "landing";
      landing.style.position = "absolute";
      landing.style.left = "50%";
      landing.style.top = "50%";
      landing.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%)";
      landing.appendChild(sin);
      landing.appendChild(sup);
      document.body.appendChild(landing);
  };
  App.prototype.signIn = function () {
      document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("landing"));
      var user = document.createElement("input");
      user.type = "text";
      user.id = "username";
      user.placeholder = " username";
      user.style.border = "1px solid";
      user.style.width = "150px";
      var pass = document.createElement("input");
      pass.type = "password";
      pass.id = "password";
      pass.placeholder = " password";
      pass.style.border = "1px solid";
      pass.style.width = "150px";
      var okay = document.createElement("button");
      okay.innerHTML = "Sign in";

  //I can't get the isValid function to execute.

      okay.onclick = this.isValid;
      var signin = document.createElement("div");
      signin.id = "signin";
      signin.style.position = "absolute";
      signin.style.left = "50%";
      signin.style.top = "50%";
      signin.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%)";
      signin.appendChild(user);
      signin.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      signin.appendChild(pass);
      signin.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
      signin.appendChild(okay);
      document.body.appendChild(signin);
  };
  App.prototype.signUp = function () {
      alert("alert!");
  };
  App.prototype.isValid = function () {
      alert("alert!");
  };
  return App;
  }());
  window.onload = function () {
      var app = new App();
  };
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well, you got the entire app, the html and the javascript that is referenced within the html. As I am new to stackoverflow and javascript I am not sure what else might be needed. I was hoping some expert javascript coder could immediately pinpoint the problem. this is as good as my limited knowledge will get. your link and downvote did me no good, if i can't get answer with what i gave above I will just have to try another resource.

Comment: To get people on SO to help you.  My advice is to first make it as easy as possible.  Seen as your saying this is all your code is to turning this into a snippet would really help.   This time I have done this for you, but in the future if you click the `<>` button in the editor you get a nice jsbin type playground to show your code.   I can now run your code to see the issue.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, and your link really didn't explain much to me, especially didn't explain this snippet and playground feature. thank you for taking the time to explain it further. Do you know why I cant get the button to execute the isValid function. Do you have a link that could explain what I am doing wrong or misunderstanding?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Back to your problem, your `this` context on event bindings are the actually control.  so this -> `sin.onclick = this.signIn;`  so when `signIn` is called this will be the button, it's not the `this` of the object as you might expect.  There are a few ways to solve this, but for now try -> `sin.onclick = this.signIn.bind(this)`

Comment: thank you, now I have to understand what the code fix you gave me is actually doing. you been a great help. I was stumped for hours. Now I actually have something to work off of.

Answer (score 0):

**This** is a classic scoping problem.

When the `okay` button is added, `this` is not pointing where you thinking it is pointing.

You assumed `this` would be referring to the `App` function. But the `okay` button is not created by the `App` function, is it created by the `sin` button. And that's why `this`, in that location, points to the `sin` button, and since there no `isValid` function in the `sin` button, you don't get the alert you wanted.

To fix this you can change `this.isValid` to `App.prototype.isValid`.

```
// from this
okay.onclick = this.isValid;

// to this
okay.onclick = App.prototype.isValid;
```

This will get the desired behavior.